# Cooked mode off when launching a Msys2 compiled executable

Tags: c++, gcc, input, msys2

Have noticed a problem when compiling with Msys2 a C++ code.
Seems like the executable when launched has the terminal input on raw mode. It's crucial to my exe to be able to get the input from user in a cooked mode.

After quite a struggle to understand why terminal was on raw mode, I've noticed that when I compile my code through MinGW and not Msys2, the executable behave as I want. The input is now cooked. The fact is my application need the filesystem lib which is not inlcuded in MinGW, on the contrary Msys2 has it.

I'll give you an example, this is my simple code to check cooked/raw mode:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string line;
    getline(cin, line);
    cout << line << endl;
    getline(cin, line);
}
```

If I input something like "Helllo" and I want to fix it backspacing an "l", it becomes like this with raw mode (Msys2 case) "Hel lo". The last 2 letters stay still and a blank space substitutes the "l" I Just backspaced. On the contrary with my code compiled with MinGW the from "Helllo" it goes to "Hello" correctly. Another big issue is that it seems like my backspace has no effect with raw mode on (msys2 case). Look at this example:

> ```
> Hel lo 
> Helllo
> ```

The first line is my input, the second line is the output of the executable. I've just followed the example I made on point number 1. Imagine like I've done this (it's difficult cause I can't post pictures rn)

1. I've written wrongly the word "Helllo"
2. Then I decided to fix it and go back with the left arrow to the mid "l" and used backspace to delete it.
3. The input line is not correct and the letters stay still like this "Hel lo"
4. I press enter and the output is "Helllo" like nothing has changed in my input line since I pressed backspace.

Doing the same actions with a MinGW compiled exe will have this input:

> Hello

And this output:

> Hello

working correctly. How can I fix this?

Resolved:

Full credit for this answer is from a comment by @HolyBlackCat

To anyone who happens to have the same problem as me, it seems like the problem is the Msys2 environment in which you're compiling. Msys gives some problem, just try any other suitable solution like MinGW64.

Comment: MSYS2 is one of MinGW distributions, so it's unclear what you call *the* MinGW.

Comment: What [MSYS2 environment](https://www.msys2.org/docs/environments/) do you use?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I think I'm using MSYS, the one with "/usr" as prefix. Sorry about that, I recogn i'm a newbie to this type of thing. Glad you're helping me. Anyway with MinGW i mean the MinGW you can install without msys2. There's an installer which helps you selecting the packages you want. I don't know how to explain it more precisely than this

Comment: *"don't know how to explain it more"* By linking the site where you got it.

Comment: *"I think I'm using MSYS"* Normally you want anything but MSYS. MSYS is wonky, it uses a Cygwin fork, and unless you specifically want Cygwin, you don't want it. Prefer something like MINGW64 or UCRT64. For that, uninstall your `gcc` package just in case, install `mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc` (for MINGW64), and reopen your terminal in the right environment (confirm this by checking the magenta text in the terminal prompt).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat just solved the problem changing msys2 environment from msys to minGW64. Thanks for helping

Comment: 55.1% of MSYS2 problems are just people compiling in the wrong environment.

Comment: i posted on pervious version of this question, I was using vs2022 - worked fine there